# Modify frame of cell elements selected with viewWithTag does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, frame

I have a tableview with custom cell in storyboard

the cell identifier is : `MyCustomCellIdentifier`

the frame of the label is : `{ { 15.0f, 178.0f }, { 280.0f, 40.0f } }`

I basically want to change the frame of a UILabel according to the size of the text.

Let's say that my UILabel is tagged : `1` in my StoryBoard

In the function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCellIdentifier"];
    UILabel *myLabel = [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    NSLog(@"frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myLabel.frame)); //frame {{0, 295}, {0, 0}}
    myLabel.text = @"myText";

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(FLT_MAX, myLabel.frame.size.height);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    CGRect newFrame = myLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
    myLabel.frame = newFrame;
    NSLog(@"frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myLabel.frame)); //frame {{0, 295}, {80, 0}}

    return cell;
}
```

Why there are those 0 value instead of the actual values from the storyboard ?
How to initialize the frame of the label to have the correct value ?

Why if I set the values programatically it does not change the displayed label frame?

When I scroll down and scroll back to the previous cell it actually display the correct frame but not during the first display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of auto layout being on (it's on by default). To fix it, you can either turn auto layout off, or use constraints rather then setting frames to change the size of your label. It's not clear to me why you're trying to set the width of the label this way -- if you just set it to "Size To Fit Content" in IB, it will automatically resize to fit the text (in the width direction anyway).